# Find the sum of this series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let the $r^{th}$ term of a series be given by $T_r=r/(1-3r^{2}+r^{4})$.

Then find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}T_r$$

I could think of only one way- that was to factorise the denominator as $(r^{2}-r-1)(r^{2}+r-1)$, write the numerator as $(1/2)[(r^{2}+r-1)-(r^{2}-r-1)]$ and then cancel terms and solve. Is their a better approach to this problem ??

Comment: why better? Have you checked the partial sum here?

Comment: Yes.. I thought that there could be something better..

Comment: try using the definition of definite integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}r/(1-3r^{2}+r^{4})$$
$T_r=r/(1-3r^{2}+r^{4})=1/2(\frac{1}{r^{2}-r-1}-\frac{1}{r^{2}+r-1})$.

Notice that  $T_{r+1}=1/2(\frac{1}{r^{2}+r-1}-\frac{1}{r^{2}+3r-1})$

$L=(1/2) \lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}+n-1 }) =\frac{1}{2}$

I am sorry for my poor english

Comment: That is exactly what I did.. Any other methods ?